# command line utility for linux to decode SCSI CDB

Tags: scsi, utility

I need to see commands which send to my scsi device. I enabled scsi debug in kernel and got CDB. It looks like this: `2a 00 00 a0 09 90 00 00 08 00`.

I'm searching for command line utility to decode them in human-readable format. So far I found one java-script library to do this. Is there such utility for command line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While over a year has passed hopefully this information will help others like me. I dont have a command line utility but I do have specifications which can help.

If your posted CDB is correct then 0x2a is the Write (10) command which means the length of the command is 10 bytes according to Seagate and this is what you have posted.

https://www.seagate.com/staticfiles/support/disc/manuals/scsi/100293068a.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I found that `sg_sense` utility can decode CDB as well, using `--cdb` parameter. (Package sg3-utils).